# `git pull --rebase` will lost local commit

Tags: git, github, rebase

As described in the titled, i had some problem about `git pull --rebase` command.

Firstly, i have a local repo and cloned from `origin`, then i do some commits on branch `master`, and then i want put my local commit on the top of `master`, so i run `git pull origin master --rebase`. After run this command, i found my local is update with `origin/master` but lost my previous commits.

I'm very confused with this situation, and i found that i have set `origin` to different push and fetch url with `git remote set-url --push origin newURL(my fork repo)`, if i set push and fetch to same url, the `git pull --rebase` works well.

So, is there some conflicts with `git remote set-url --push origin newURL` and `git pull --rebase`? Or i missed something?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: first : to quiet your mind, your previous commits are not lost ; git has a big safety net built in, called the reflog. If you run `git reflog`, you will see that your original commits are still there. Don't touch these for the moment, but know that you still have them.

Comment: Can you run `git status`, and paste the output of that command in your question ? Chances are the "rebase" step of `git pull --rebase` is currently stopped because you have conflicts

Comment: Thanks for you reply!@LeGEC . I can touch my commit by `git reset mycommit-sha1`, and when i run `git status` it's shows "nothing to commit, working tree clean" after i ran  `git pull --rebase`. I found how to fix it, but i just curious about why `git pull --rebase` doesn't work when `origin` with different push and fetch url.

Comment: I just now clone a new repo from github, and then i set `origin` push url to my remote repo, and then i do some commits, and then i push local repo to my remote(without this operation, the `git pull --rebase` will works well). At last, i run `git pull --rebase`(assume original repo has new commits ), and i get these:"Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master",  my commits just gone.

Comment: `git rebase origin/master` does several things, one of them is : in the list of commits it is going to replay on top of `origin/master`, it tries to spot what commits are *already* part of `origin/master` ; if a commit is identified as already present, `git rebase` will ignore it. When you look at the history of `origin/master`, do you see some commits which already contain your changes ?

Comment: I have already looked for it, but it was exactly gone. BTW, if i run `git fetch` and `git rebase origin/master` instead of  `git pull --rebase`, it also works well.

Comment: Can you try my procedure and make sure it's not my misoperation?