# git pull --rebase: lost my current commit

Tags: git

As described in the titled, i had some problem about `git pull --rebase` command.

I do some commits on a branch, then so i run `git pull --rebase`. After run this command, i found my local is update but lost my previous commits.

`git reflog` output

[image]

after pull rebase

[image]

I have some important chages in my thing

Comment: Provide a [mcve] and someone can diagnose the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66981965/git-pull-rebase-will-lost-local-commit

something similar

Comment: The reflog is not a history so much as a list of places you've been. Just because `commit : test` is `HEAD@{2}` in the reflog, that doesn't mean it's going to appear in the `staging` log. What we need to see is what commands you gave. And after all, the fact that you see it in the reflog should comfort you, because it means you can extract it from there if you're worried about the state of things in it.

Comment: `git pull --rebase` after `git commit -m "test"`

Comment: generally i  do `git -m commit "comment"` and then do `git pull --rebase` and `git push`

Comment: @Santhosh: "Something similar" is not helpful. If my car won't start because it's out of petrol/gas, and your car won't start because the battery is flat, they're similar, but putting fuel in your car won't make it start.